# Chained Packages in Advanced Installer

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, advanced-installer

I am trying to launch another MSI while installing a first one. I found out about the chained packages. I followed this [tuto](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-chained-packages.html), everything works great but I'd like to go further in the settings.

My final goal is to avoid, for the secondary installer, the install folder selection, and automatically install the files in the same folder as the principal MSI.

Is it possible ? If not, what could I do to reach my purpose ?

Any help would be greatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main MSI install folder property is APPDIR. To achieve what you want you can set the install folder property of the chained MSI to the APPDIR property value. This can be done by setting the [Properties field](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/chained-package-page.html) like this:

```
CHAINED_INSTALL_DIR_PROP = "[APPDIR]"
```

Also the chained package could be configured to install without full UI so the user cannot select the install folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm a newbie with Advanced Installer. I think I am missing something, I did what you said, however it doesn't work, the installation folder of the chained package didn't change. Actually, I think I need to set the property to be launched somewhere, or something else ? Here I just define a property, called _CHAINED_INSTALL_DIR_PROP_, but how can I launch it ? Hope I make myself clear enough...

Comment: Ok i found my mistake. I needed to add the property in the chained package, I didn't get it at the beginning. Now it works great, thank you.

Comment: great. glad to help.